# PHP how to echo two variables

Tags: php, for-loop

I want to show a defined variable by using `for` loop like this code:

```
<?php
  define("V_1","Variable1");
  define("V_2","Variable2");
  define("V_3","Variable3");
  for ($f=1;$f<4;$f++){
    echo "<p>".V_.$f."</p>";
  }
?>
```

Is there any one can help me with this?

Comment: `define` creates constants, not variables. Use an array, not separate constants.

Comment: To echo your `constants`: http://php.net/manual/en/function.constant.php

Comment: Is not there any way to echo this?

Comment: `echo constant('V_'.$f);` But learn how to quote string literals like `'V_'`, and the difference between constants and variables.... both are fundamentals of any kind of programming.

Comment: That was the answer, thank you @MarkBaker